# Почему форма отображается ниже текста а не рядом?

Tags: html, javascript

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/8caem/)
Как поставить рядом.

И еще сразу вопрос. Можно ли обойтись без формы, чтоб при нажатии "Enter" у input узнать value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как поставить рядом.

Форма - это блочный элемент, поэтому всё, что перед ней или за ней, будет по умолчанию распологатся на других строках.

> Можно ли обойтись без формы, чтоб при
> нажатии "Enter" у input узнать value?

Можно. Смотрите [простенький вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8caem/2/).

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert(this.value);
    }
};
```